# DataTables plugin: if not sortable remove text-decoration from column header

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using the DataTables plugin, and on certain columns I have set `"bSortable": false`.  On those same columns I would like to remove the text underline and cursor pointer from the column header as well.

I created a class called `removeFormat` which I would like to apply to JUST the column headers.

```
.removeFormat {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

How can I do so??

I was hoping I could use something like `sClass`.  Unfortunately, that only adds the classes to the table cells.

If creating a CSS class and adding it to the column header is not the right direction I should go in, is there a standard method which DataTables has which I can use for this specific purpose?

**UPDATE:**

I'd like to add a function directly to the column I am interested in changing.  For instance:

```
           {
                "mData": null,
                "sWidth": "5%",
                "bSortable": false,
                "sClass": "alignCenter"
            }
```

Comment: Since sClass actually does work, I've removed my rather more cumbersome answer. You probably just need to increase specificity. Fiddle around in dev tools and add 'body ' in front of your selector (or some other ancestor with an ID).

Comment: @isherwood Question though... I read around that sClass wasn't added to the TH.  Is that not true anymore?  I'm looking in DevTools and see it there, but I just want to double check with you?

Comment: I was referring to your comment on my question, where you said, "... I just noticed that the class gets added to the TH elements when I put it in sClass", and indicated that CSS adjustments would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after playing around with it a bit.

In my case the sClass applied the class to both the table cells and the table header.  So I just needed to add the class to the list:

```
"sClass": "alignCenter removeFormat"
```

I also just made sure that my class was specific enough that it applied to only the table headers and it applied to the element on hover:

```
th.removeFormat div:hover {}
```

That fixed it!